# Problem with Vue: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I recently updated my repositories, and now I'm having these issues every time I build.

I already tried to go back to the previous point, but still the same. I found a problem with the style sheet. I use Tailwind, and when I import a sheet inside app.css if this sheet has these classes:
transform -translate-x-1/2 translate-y-1/2 can't compile

I took those classes out and put them in app.css, but when I use npm run watch, it compiles the first time, but if I do another modification, I have to save app.css again to compile correctly.

> ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use[2]!./resources/css/app.css)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>
> Problem with Vue building Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js)

**package.json**

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue resources/js/",
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/sanitize-html": "^2.3.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.7",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier-vue": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.14.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.42",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "vue-loader": "^16.3.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@chenfengyuan/vue-barcode": "^2.0.0-beta",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-4",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.3.0",
    "ag-grid-vue3": "^25.3.1",
    "click-outside-vue3": "^4.0.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.11.4",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.6",
    "peru-ubigeo": "^0.0.3",
    "qrcode.vue": "^3.2.2",
    "quagga": "^0.12.1",
    "twitter-widgets": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-3-sanitize": "^0.1.3",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-rc.1",
    "vue-cookie-next": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-currency-input": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-debounce": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vue-upload-drop-images": "^1.0.7",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
}
```

I use Vue 3 and Laravel 8